# Raspberry PI : Pi-Hole with 2x ethernet unable to get eth1 traffic directed via pi-hole

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, pihole

So where do I start. well after about 20 attempts maybe 30hours I have decided to ask for help :(

so what am I trying to do? Well, I have a raspberry pi with 1x onboard Ethernet which is eth0 and I have a Ethernet to USB that is eth1, on eth1 is a basic ceiling mount access point and from that we have 30-70 mobile phones connecting however I am trying to limit the mobile phones or any device connecting to the AP to one website only, eth0 is connected to a switch and I have no access to the router or any other part of the network I have one port on the switch.

What have I tried:

1: I have done a direct bridge but then I can't restrict anything to one website

2: Next on the list was to forward traffic from one eth0 to eth1 but its not an WiFi dongle and everything out there is wlan0 and so related; can't get it to work

3: Pi-Hole got that working on eth0 but cant get eth1 to work with it tried different ways of configuration but not able to get any of the devices work or get an IP so.

With that said; I am trying to figure out where to go from here. I know it can be done as it was setup like this before but the SD card corrupted, don't have a back up an I did not do the original setup.

Any help or even direction would honestly be a huge help.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What you want is called a “Captive Portal”. The interface types (Wi-Fi, Ethernet or otherwise) do not matter.

Comment: I have seen that around, going to try it, thank you.